# return a message and put in a new column after compare values in a dataset (using pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I need to see if the values in column `Deathrate` is lower than 9 and return `balanced`. If isn't return `Urgent` and put all this in a new column `Humanitarian Help`. I tried this first:

```
new = country_data.filter(items=['Country', 'Deathrate']).where(country_data['Deathrate'] > 9)
new = new.dropna()
new
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

country_data['Humanitarian Help'] = np.where(country_data['Deathrate'] < 9, "balanced", "Deathrate")
```

Note that I changed `>` (greater than) to `<` (less than) per "`Deathrate` is **lower** than 9"